# What is the computational complexity of Spectrum Estimation Algorthms and What they depend upon?

Tags: fft, frequency-spectrum, power-spectral-density, estimation, spectrum-estimation

There are lots of spectrum estimation techniques, each with some pros and cons.
 Algorithms like:

- Music
- Welch's method
- Yule-Walker AR method
- Periodogram
- modified covariance method
- multitaper method (MTM)
- Spectrogram using short-time
- Fourier transform
- Burg method covariance method

and many many other.
 However I do not know which is more proper for embedded system implementation, because I don't know their computational complixy so I am more interested in mathematical estimation of computational complexity of this methods and especially how their complexity is affected with factors like input noise, spectrum occupation, etc?

I'v found [Spectrum Estimaton Methods](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/why-so-many-methods-of-computing-psd), which greatly explains these methods, but does not compare them from computational complexity point of view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The computational requirements for various non-parametric PSD estimation methods is discussed in [*]. The complexity depends on the length $N$ of your data record. Roughly speaking:

1. The most straightforward periodogram method which calculates the magnitude squared of the DFT of $N$ samples has a complexity of $N \log N$.
2. Bartlett and Welch methods use $M$ overlapping windows of length $M$ each and calculate ~$N/M$ DFTs, so the complexity is $\frac{N}{M} \cdot M \log M = N \log M$.
3. Yule-Walker method for an $AR(p)$ inverts a $p\times p$ Toeplitz matrix which has a complexity of $O(p^2)$. The Toeplitz matrix itself is formed from estimates of the autocorrelation values calculated at $p$ different lags from the $N$-long data vector giving a complexity $O(Np)$. So the total complexity is $O(p^2 + Np)$.
4. MUSIC estimates an $M \times M$ autocovariance matrix from data by averaging the outer products of, say, $N/M$ $M$-long blocks of the original $N$-long signal and then calculates the eigendecomposition of the $M\times M$ autocovariance matrix which is $O(M^3)$. ($M$ is chosen by the user. For a signal with $p$ frequency components, choose $M>p$.)

I don't think the complexity is affected by input noise level because the algorithms themselves do not change.

**Reference**

[*] J. Proakis Digital Signal Processing, 4th Edition Ch. 14 
https://www.pearsonhighered.com/program/Proakis-Digital-Signal-Processing-4th-Edition/PGM258227.html