# How to compare PSD methods?

Tags: fft, power-spectral-density

I am trying to compare several PSD methods to determine the most suitable method for my application. Does anyone know a good approach to start with? I am relatively new to this field of topic.

I could possibly compare the results of the psd methods, the computational complexity and the resolution of the results.

Comment: See https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/2096/why-so-many-methods-of-computing-psd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to compare PSD methods?

Same way you deal with any type of engineering problem of this sort:

1. Write down requirements of your application. What are the priorities, sensitivities and minimum quantitative requirements/thresholds.?
2. Write down the properties, features and parameter space of the different PSD approaches that you have found.
3. Compare #1 and #2, find the PSD method and parameters that meets your requirements the best and/or has the best set of tradeoffs.